# Deploying WCF Service on Azure : Web Role or Worker Role?

Tags: wcf, azure

I am evaluating the various options to deploy a web service in Azure. Presently, the web service would be consumed only by a front end UI which will be deployed as a separate web role within the same cloud service that would be hosting the web service. However, the web service would be exposed in its own right at a later stage. Apparently, web services can be hosted from within either Web Role or from a worker role. Could you please throw some light on pros and cons of either approach? Which of these approaches would you recommend for my scnario?

Answer (score 3):

A web role assumes that the application will be hosted in IIS. If your service does not require any of the benefits provided by IIS or its HTTP stack, then hosting it in a worker role may do you perfectly fine and also provide you a lower resource utilization for that service (since there's no "overhead" for the IIS server).

Comment: How do I determine that? I've always used IIS by default, never actually considering **choosing** it. I just went with it "as always"...